# How does Venmo bring an app into the foreground in iOS for their iBeacon feature?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

From http://blog.venmo.com/hf2t3h4x98p5e13z82pl8j66ngcmry/2014/7/8/introducing-background-nearby-with-ibeacons, they suggest that they were able to forcibly bring app into the foreground:

"Whenever a device enters a beacon region, it briefly launches the Venmo app into the foreground in order to broadcast its peer identifier over the MPC framework, thus establishing a Nearby connection. In other words, whenever our users open Venmo to pay or charge the people they are around, they can instantly emit a beacon signal that momentarily wakes up their friends’ devices to connect and populate the user's Nearby drawer."

Every post on here about this suggests this isn't possible. Can someone explain?

Comment: You are misreading. It doesn't say _they_ launch it. It says _it_ (the device) launches it, which is absolutely true; that is what region monitoring does. I suspect that "foreground" is just a misprint for "background" but I could be mistaken about that.

Comment: I also suspect that "foreground" is a simplification and that Venmo actually takes advantage of the iOS location *background* capabilities (the iOS location background mode is also applicable to iBeacon)...meaning the app doesn't actually enter the foreground, but is launched into the background to complete the necessary tasks even if the app has been terminated. Here's a tiny bit of info from the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7

Comment: @lyndsey-scott is absolutely right.  His comment should be an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: @davidgyoung OK, I'll make it a proper answer then. Thanks for the affirmation. :)

Comment: @davidgyoung And not that I really care, but "her." ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that "foreground" is a simplification and that Venmo actually takes advantage of the iOS location background capabilities (the iOS location background mode is also applicable to iBeacon); meaning the app doesn't actually enter the foreground, but is launched into the background to complete the necessary tasks even if the app has been terminated.

Here's a bit of info from the docs about iBeacon background usage: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7